# (UE4) How to get an overlap event with a poseable mesh

Tags: unreal-engine4

i moved a poseable mesh with Set Bone Location By Name and Set Bone Rotation By Name. 
Now i tried to handle the collision but i did not get any overlap events whatsoever.

The mesh i used has collision enabled and generated the overlap events but as soon as i moved the mesh with the methods mentioned above, i did not get the events.

Now i want to know if it is even possible to get overlap events after moving the mesh?

Answer (score 0):

BeginOverlap is called on overlap, it won't detect things already inside the collision.

Have you tried using GetOverlappedActors()? It's a code function but I think there's also a blueprint node.